# Insane Chrome issue...Chrome renders twisties?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Probably I'm being stupid and overlooking something, but I am having a bizarre issue that only occurs in Chrome (12.0.7, but maybe other versions as well). Check out this site:

http://www.jungledragon.com

On the right side, you will notice a community update panel. This is how it looks in any major browser except Chrome:

[image]

And here is how it renders in Chrome:

[image]

It renders twisties? When you click on one, it expands the row. Clicking again collapses the row. Nowhere in my code do I have any markup to implement such behavior. Is this some kind of special behavior because I am using figure tags? I tested this site in Chrome before and it was no issue then, so it could be a recent bug.

Comment: in Chrome 11.0 renders as it should. no twisies

Comment: I cannot reproduce the bug with Chromium 11.0

Comment: @maephisto. Thanks for confirming, thats how I remember it when I last tested it. So this seems like a Chrome 12 issue.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6195329/405015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `details` element is supposed to exhibit the behaviour you're experiencing in Chrome.

[The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element):

> The details element represents a
>   disclosure widget from which the user
>   can obtain additional information or
>   controls.
>
> ..
>
> The open content attribute is a
>   boolean attribute. If present, it
>   indicates that the details are to be
>   shown to the user. If the attribute is
>   absent, the details are not to be
>   shown.
>
> When the element is created, if the
>   attribute is absent, the details
>   should be hidden; if the attribute is
>   absent, the details should be shown.
>   Subsequently, if the attribute is
>   removed, then the details should be
>   hidden; if the attribute is added, the
>   details should be shown.
>
> **The user agent should allow the user
>   to request that the details be shown
>   or hidden.** To honor a request for the
>   details to be shown, the user agent
>   must set the open attribute on the
>   element to the value open. To honor a
>   request for the details to be hidden,
>   the user agent must remove the open
>   attribute from the element.

Some version of Chrome 12 (dev channel) added proper support for opening and closing the `details` element.

According to http://caniuse.com/#search=details, Chrome is the only browser to support this at the moment.

To fix this, I think you should replace the `details` element with some other element.