# How can you hide the arrow that is displayed by default on the HTML5 <details> element in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

I now its still early but I also know you guys are on top of it.

I want to use the [HTML5 details element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element):

```html
<details>
    <summary>What's the HTML5 details element?</summary>
    <p>The details element represents a disclosure widget from which the user can obtain additional information or controls.</p>
</details>
```

As of this writing, Chrome 12 beta is the only browser to actually give the details element functionality (clicking on summary toggles the details content). So to answer the following question you'll probably want to use that browser.

**Do you know how you can hide the arrow that is displayed by default on a details element in Chrome?**

It's a bit like the default styling of `<input type="search" />` in Webkit (see http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/). You can change it but it's not that obvious.

**EDIT**

Tried the following CSS code with no success:

```
details,
details summary {
padding-left:0;
background-image:none;
-webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

There probably is a chance we will need to target it with some weird pseudo selector like `details::-webkit-details-disclosure-widget` or there's currently no way to change things at all.

Furthermore I found this in [the specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-details-element-0):

> The first container is expected to
> contain at least one line box, and
> that line box is expected to contain a
> disclosure widget (typically a
> triangle), horizontally positioned
> within the left padding of the details
> element. That widget is expected to
> allow the user to request that the
> details be shown or hidden.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

I didn't plan to answer my own question but I have the solution.

- Source:
  http://trac.webkit.org/timeline?from=2011-04-15T16%3A33%3A41-0700&precision=second
- More about the recommendation for the disclosure widget:
  http://mail-archive.com/whatwg@lists.whatwg.org/msg26129.html

Code

```
details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display:none;
}
```

Note that the disclosure widget will still be displayed if you don't provide a summary element, which is allowed by the spec.

Comment: The only problem I see is that this won't work cross-browser once others start supporting `<DETAILS>`

Comment: When they do, they will probably add their own prefixed version, much like with the current way to style an input placeholder.

Comment: Had a wierd display issue involving the stupid triangle and chrome dev tools didn't show me the selector for this thing. Thanks!

Comment: This works for Chrome, but to support Firefox this is needed as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6195588/1293492 These 2 answers should be merged.

Comment: I respect that this answer was great at the time, but really by now we should have a nice cross-browser, standards-compliant solution here i.s.o webkit specific.

Comment: Do either of these work in Safari? No Safari here to test with.

Comment: This works with chrome but it doesn't work with firefox, you need to  add ```summary {list-style: none;} ``` for it to work in firefox.

Comment: Its worth noting that there is now a non-webkit prefixed selector for this element:
```:marker```

To acheive this you need 
```::marker{
display:none;
}
summary{
list-style: none
}```

Comment: If you still want the widget to take up space (e.g., if you want to align the text of several consecutive `details` elements, not all of which are expandable) then you should use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`.

Comment: You probably want to use selector `details > summary::marker` to match only the part you want to change.

Comment: This doesnt work in chrome. I've used `font-size: 0px;`

Comment: I can confirm that on iOS **15.5** the `summary::-webkit-details-marker` is still needed for the triangle bullet thingy to be correctly selected and hidden.

Answer (score 116):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#Customizing_the_disclosure_widget

You can achieve this with:

```css
details > summary {
  list-style: none;
}
details > summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: to me this is the most suitable answer b'se it worked for me on both firefox, safari and chrome

Comment: Some are saying the webkit prefix is obsolete and you only need to use ::marker. I'm not finding that to be the case in iOS 15.4 so I'm including both.

Comment: details > summary {list-style: none;} worked for all browsers to me

Comment: I can confirm that on iOS **15.5** the `summary::-webkit-details-marker` is still needed for the triangle bullet thingy to be correctly selected and hidden.

Comment: @Sam is it still the case in 2023?

Answer (score 81):

Revisiting in 2021, the `::-webkit-details-marker` n̶o̶ ̶l̶o̶n̶g̶e̶r̶ works only for Safari. For all other bmodern browsers, you need to target the pseudo-element `::marker` like so:

```css
details > summary {
  list-style: none;
}

details > summary::marker, /* Latest Chrome, Edge, Firefox */ 
details > summary::-webkit-details-marker /* Safari */ {
  display: none;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/eyecatchup/pen/BamvBQa)

Comment: All the other answers doesnt work in 2021, please use this target instead guys. Thanks op.

Comment: @eyecatchup do you know how to prevent it from opening? I don't want to show what <details> is hiding.

Comment: @Luis try <details onclick="this.open='false';">

Comment: This is wrong. On iOS 15.4 which is the latest version today I still needed to include the `webkit-details-marker` to hide it.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Well, OP asked for Chrome. But you're right. Confirmed with Safari on Mac OS. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @eyecatchUp thanks for updating and sorry if I sounded a bit blunt with 'This is wrong.'

Comment: I can confirm that on iOS **15.5** the `summary::-webkit-details-marker` is still needed for the triangle bullet thingy to be correctly selected and hidden.

Answer (score 29):

I'm not sure if this will work, given that my current computer will not run Chrome and I do not have access to the computer I normally use, but try adding this to your css file:

```
details > summary:first-of-type {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Do tell me if it works, I only saw it in a recommendation, not an official spec.

Comment: This works for Firefox, but to support Chrome this is needed as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6202729/1293492 These 2 answers should be merged.

Comment: Works on `code-insiders-1.88.0-1710157206.el8`'s default Markdown previewer, too.

Answer (score 8):

I find this works well enough.

```css
::-webkit-details-marker {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  font-size:0px
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am on Firefox 65.0.1 and can remove the arrow this way:

```
details > summary {display:block}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see in my example that it's just a matter of overwriting a display fromlist-item to other.
Hence nowadays we use that type the same way as we use flex, grid et c. - all these've got their referral attributes.

:)

**My answer:**
Just run devtools and set custom value for attributes display and/or list-style-type,list-style.

```css
details{
background:yellow;
border-radius: 4px;
cursor:pointer;
}

summary{
/* ANSWER BELOW*/
    list-style: none;
/* ANSWER ABOVE*/
    background:green;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<details>detail
<summary>summary</summary
</details>
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing the display to 'block' will remove the arrow.

```
summary {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution in 2022., and it wokrs.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on iOS.

Comment: Doesn't work on Safari 15.5, works on Chrome for instance.

`::-webkit-details-marker { display: none; }` shoudl remove the marker on Safari

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me, since the highest rated on did not work on Chrome for me. It's a variation of the original solution.

```
details summary {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: This does not work on Safari.

Answer (score 1):

A great solution working in React / NextJs is something like:

```
details summary::marker {
  content: '';
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Safari

Answer (score -1):

My answer: Just run devtools and set custom value for attributes display and/or list-style-type,list-style.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).