# How to remove the arrow on the side of the summary element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a summary in a details element:

```
<details>
  <summary>Hello</summary>
</details>
```

I have tried:

```
summary {
  display: block; /* works in firefox */
  list-style: none; /* works in firefox */
}

/* didn't work in any browser */
summary::marker,
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

/* Solution for Chrome and Safari? */
```

From this question [How can you hide the arrow that is displayed by default on the HTML5 <details> element in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195329/how-can-you-hide-the-arrow-that-is-displayed-by-default-on-the-html5-details-e).

But none of those solutions *actually* works in chrome.

How do I remove this arrow in chrome too?

Comment: `details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display:none;
}` (copied from the link in your question) does work in Chrome v80 https://jsfiddle.net/e2jLzumd/

Comment: `details > summary::-webkit-details-marker {  display: none; }` works for me in chrome 80, too. See bottom of this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#Customizing_the_disclosure_widget

Comment: remove the line: `summary::marker,` from your css - it seems to be breaking chrome

Comment: This should be the right answer

Answer (score 6):

This works for me!

```
summary::marker {
  content: "";
}
```

Comment: No effect in 17.3.

Answer (score -1):

```
summary {
  &::marker {
    content: "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Do note that this is SASS and not pure CSS

Answer (score -5):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <style>
            summary {
                display: block;
                /* works in firefox */
                list-style: none;
                /* works in firefox */
            }

            summary::after {
                display: block;
                list-style: none;
            }

            summary::-webkit-details-marker {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <details>
            <summary>Hello</summary>
        </details>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You seem to have copy/pasted the code from the question that the OP says doesn't work. There's no explanation about what, if anything, you've changed or why it should solve the problem.

Comment: @Quentin: not quite, they used `summary::after` instead of `summary::marker`. Not that just posting the code without explanation makes this a helpful answer.