# Remove arrow from the summary HTML

Tags: html

there's a way to remove the arrow and leave only my custom image con the summary code in HTML?

here's the code I used:

```html
<center>
<h1>
PASCAL LOTA</h1>
<details>
  <summary><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Gqx6lkmLq_k/XoiKBHj5L9I/AAAAAAAAAi8/gohuLTm_RI8mHLSn5acQTeonA7RYSGyrwCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/System%2Brequirements.png" /></summary>
   - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.<br />

  All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.<br />

</details>
</center>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think it already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195329/how-can-you-hide-the-arrow-that-is-displayed-by-default-on-the-html5-details-e

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you hide the arrow that is displayed by default on the HTML5 <details> element in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195329/how-can-you-hide-the-arrow-that-is-displayed-by-default-on-the-html5-details-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it to go away by changing the CSS attribute of the marker to not be displayed. So the arrow goes by the name of details-marker and we set its `display:none` which stops it from being drawn in.
EDIT: I added in a bit of code to stop the `<summary>` from highlighting blue on click, i thought it was ugly so i fixed it.

```html
<style>
summary:focus {
outline:none !important
}
details > summary::-webkit-details-marker {
display:none;
}
</style>
<center>
<h1>
PASCAL LOTA</h1>
<details>
  <summary><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Gqx6lkmLq_k/XoiKBHj5L9I/AAAAAAAAAi8/gohuLTm_RI8mHLSn5acQTeonA7RYSGyrwCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/System%2Brequirements.png" /></summary>
   - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.<br />

  All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.<br />

</details>
</center>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend! Yes, I wanted to remove the blue highlighting too! Thanks again!

Comment: Paolo, if this answered your question please hit the transparent check mark underneath the arrows on this answer to signify that this post was indeed answered. Im glad i could help :)