# How to remove marker from <details> element on Safari?

Tags: css, safari, html-tag-details

I have tried the many solutions suggested on other posts. None work on macOS Safari nor iOS Safari. What am I missing, how can I remove the triangle-shaped marker from “Bob”?

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

The stylesheet below uses more code than I originally wrote, but it shows how I’m trying everything suggested by other posts.

And it overuses `!important` flags to be extra sure they’re working.

It also uses bizarre colors to make obvious which elements are which.

A live demo is here: https://jsbin.com/cepufayodo/edit?html,css,output

```
<nav class="panel" id="panel">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="major" href="#alice">Alice</a></li>
        <li><details class="major">
            <summary>Bob</summary>
            <a class="minor" href="#apple">Apple</a>
            <a class="minor" href="#berry">Berry</a>
            <a class="minor" href="#cherry">Cherry</a>
        </details></li>
        <li><a class="major" href="#carol">Carol</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none !important;
}

::-ms-details-marker,
::-moz-details-marker,
::-webkit-details-marker,
::details-marker,
::-ms-marker,
::-moz-marker,
::-webkit-marker,
::marker,
summary::-ms-details-marker,
summary::-moz-details-marker,
summary::-webkit-details-marker,
summary::details-marker,
summary::-ms-marker,
summary::-moz-marker,
summary::-webkit-marker,
summary::marker {
    color: red !important;
    content: '' !important;
    content-visibility: hidden !important;
    display: none !important;
    list-style: none !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
details,
summary {
    color: orange !important;
    display: block !important;
    list-style: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
details::before,
summary::before {
    color: yellow !important;
    content: '' !important;
    content-visibility: hidden !important;
    display: none !important;
    list-style: none !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
details::after,
summary::after {
    color: yellow !important;
    content: '' !important;
    content-visibility: hidden !important;
    display: none !important;
    list-style: none !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
.major {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    color: green;
}
.minor {
    border: 1px dashed pink;
    color: gray;
}
.panel a,
.panel summary {
    background-color: wheat;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
.panel li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Safari, at least on IOS, appears to completely ignore ::marker on details. It does work to a limited extent on list items (color and font seem to be OK).

Comment: I can't explain why Safari is not picking up the -webkit-details-marker settings you have, but it appears that what is working other than for Safari is the list-style:none and for Safari, but not e.g. Edge/Chrome (on Windows10) is the setting suggested by @carlosvidal So try summary {list-style: none; }
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
        display: none;
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195329/how-can-you-hide-the-arrow-that-is-displayed-by-default-on-the-html5-details-e)

```
details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
        display: none;
      }
```

Comment: Did you try this - it's in the code given in the question but doesn't seem to work on Safari.

Comment: Sure, check this pen in Safari

https://codepen.io/Carlos-Vidal/pen/wvOYaGE

Comment: Yes,it works on Safari, thanks for the codepen, but I can't explain why it's not therefore working in the original.

Comment: You don't have the same selector in the original. Maybe there is a certain cascade needed for it to work.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why Safari requires this specific nesting to work, but I’m glad you found a way to make it work.