# HTML5 details element for accordion

Tags: html, accordion, semantics, html-tag-details

Is the details element semantically appropriate to markup an accordion?

Example:

```
<div class="accordion">

<details open>
<summary>Section 1</summary>
</details>

<details>
<summary>Section 2</summary>
</details>

<details>
<summary>Section 3</summary>
</details>

</div>
```

I ask this question because the spec isn't very clear about its usage. It just states the details element is a disclosure widget.
I certainly don't want to use the element for something that it's not meant to be.

**EDIT**

Would something like this be better suited semantically?

```
<article role="tablist">

<header role="tab" aria-expanded>Section 1</header>
<div role="tabpanel">
</div>

<header role="tab">Section 2</header>
<div role="tabpanel">
</div>

<header role="tab">Section 3</header>
<div role="tabpanel">
</div>

</article>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `<details><summary>` elements are entirely appropriate (***and the most semantic option***) for what you're describing:

From http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element:

> The details element represents a disclosure ***widget*** from which the
>   user can ***obtain additional information*** or controls. [emphasis mine]

And this is from http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/:

> Essentially, we can use  to create an accordion-like widget that the user can toggle open and closed. Inside , we can put any sort of content we want.

Perfect usage. For example, my company has a contact page with many contact options so we could setup an accordion for it like so:

```
<details>
    <summary>Mailing Address</summary>
    <p><strong>U.S. Correspondence:</strong> 123 Main St., Washington, DC 00000-0000</p>
    <p><strong>International Correspondence:</strong> P.O.Box 1111, Washington, DC 00000-1111</p>
</details>
<details>
    <summary>Phone Numbers</summary>
    <p><strong>U.S.:</strong> 800-555-5555</p>
    <p><strong>Int'l:</strong> +1-800-555-5556</p>
</details>
```

A note on styling: good semantics shouldn't be thrown overboard to address browser-specific styling issues. A [CSS Reset](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/normalize.css) may be in order, but there's no semantic reason not to use these helpful and appropriate elements for an accordion.

**Do note: <del>Chrome currently is the only browser that supports the toggling functionality that I believe the spec intended for these elements.</del> A Javascript [fallback](http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/#fallbacks) would be useful here.

**Edit 3/2017 - See http://caniuse.com/#feat=details for support tables. This feature is now supported by almost all but IE and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<details>` for this, or you'll have this problem:

[Insane Chrome issue...Chrome renders twisties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989742/insane-chrome-issue-chrome-renders-twisties/5989963#5989963)

That's probably not desired behaviour for your accordion.

Comment: That's solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195329/how-can-you-hide-the-arrow-that-is-displayed-by-default-on-the-html5-details-el

Comment: No problem, thanks for being the first to answer this question!

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. I was searching for that and saw even MDN is using `<details>` for their sidebar menu of links. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

However, there are two problems:

## `<details>` isn't animateable

Since it's either open or not, there's no way to animate the transition - because there's no transition.

From MDN docs:

> Unfortunately, at this time there's no built-in way to animate the
> transition between open and closed.

## No support for IE

If you care, it is not supported by Internet explorer :)